# Load data from synapse spark pool to dedicated sql pool - multiple jobs for a single write action

Tags: apache-spark, azure-synapse

I have a spark code executing on Synapse spark pool as below. It reads data from dedicated SQL pool table, performs map operations and writes back data into dedicated SQL pool table.

[image: code]

Two jobs are spawned for just one write action

[image: two jobs]

In job 0 the data is written to ADLS

[image]

In job 1, same input data is re-read re-processed and written to target SQL pool table

[image: DAG of job1]

Why is Job 1 (second job) and the associated re-processing needed when Job 0 (first job) has already prepared the output data?

Driver logs capture the execution of below steps:

Step 1 - Staging directory for processed data (spark output) is created on Gen2

Step 2 - Input table is extracted on Gen2

Step 3 - Job 0 execution (output created in staging directory of step1)

Step 4 - Re-extract data from input table (this was already available in Step 2)

Step 5 - Load Job 0 output into SQL pool table

Step 6 - Execute Job 1 (where the same operations as Job 0 are re-executed)

Step 4 and Step 6 are essentially redundant

Comment: hi @Zubin Choski, if there is no issue can you share the code you have written in third cell to overwrite data in dedicated pool, as i am new to synapse and going through your query, so thought of asking you

Answer (score 0):

Two jobs are generated in the backend for just one write operation because it is internally designed in that manner.

Going into the details of what happens when you try to read and write data to dedicated sql pool from synapse spark pool. It is a two step process :

1. The data that you are reading or writing gets saves in the Azure Storage (either it be blob storage or Gen2) as an intermediate state.
2. Now spark reads the data that is saved in the Azure storage and do transformation on it. If you are writing the data, it uses polybase or Copy to transfer the data.

I am attaching the picture from the official documentation that would show you what the earlier approach was and what the new approach is.
[image]

Below are some of the official documentation reference that would allow you to understand that in more detail.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/synapse-spark-sql-pool-import-export

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/synapse-analytics

Comment: I have updated the question with the high level execution steps that were captured from driver logs. It appears that the input data is getting extracted twice (step 2 and step 4). Also, target table is available after step 5 and there is no need for the job 1 (step 6)

Comment: How are you checking that input data is extracted twice and where do you see that?

Comment: It is appearing in the Spark Driver logs. There is a CETAS statement to extract data from input table in parquet (snappy) before the Job 0. And another CETAS operation to re-extract data from input table (at a different ADLS directory) is repeated after Job 0 and before Job 1