# copy column data (which is also in dedicated SQL pool) and now pass to another table in dedicated SQL pool with Scala

Tags: azure, scala, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-synapse

I've data in dedicated SQL pool and now I want to load
this data into another table which is also in dedicated SQL pool

(i.e. Have 3+ table in dedicated SQL pool and 1 table have data, now I want to load 1 column data to another table column with Scala language)

I tried this [stack overflow source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70507025/load-data-from-synapse-spark-pool-to-dedicated-sql-pool-multiple-jobs-for-a-si) but in this solution they create new table and push data but, I want data in my existing table

--Thank you!

Comment: Sample data, DDL and expected results will help you get a better answer.  Also, why not just use SQL if the tables are in the same database?  Finally, what have you tried?

Comment: I tried this [stack overflow source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70507025/load-data-from-synapse-spark-pool-to-dedicated-sql-pool-multiple-jobs-for-a-si) but in this solution they create new table and push data but, I want data in my existing table

Comment: If you are using dedicated SQL pool the SQL is better option for manipulating data, or you only want to use scala?